# How to apply kirchoff's laws to motors in DC and AC settings

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

DC case:
is it ok to treat a motor as a variable resistor, with resistance depending on the load?

AC case:
suppose I have a motor that runs at 120V AC and is rated to X watts, how can I determine how much current it will draw if I plug it in a 120V AC source? Do I need any additional information?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?